# Add class to Html::ul() method

Tags: html, yii2

How to add class to the Html::ul() method. I have the following code:

```
<?= Html::ul($posts, ['item' => function($item, $index) {
    return Html::tag(
        'li',
        $this->render('post', ['item' => $item]),
        ['class' => 'post']
    );
}]) ?>
```

I tried below code:

```
<?= Html::ul($posts, ['item' => function($item, $index) {
    return Html::tag(
        'li',
        $this->render('post', ['item' => $item]),
        ['class' => 'post']
    );
}], [ 'class' => 'myclass' ]) ?>
```

But it's rendering the ul as following:

```
<ul 0-class="myclass">
```

Nothing is mentioned in the yii2 [document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#ul%28%29-detail).

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code worked! Might be helpful for someone.

```
echo Html::ul($posts, ['item' => function($item, $index) {
             return Html::tag(
                 'li',
                 $this->render('post', ['item' => $item]),
                ['class' => 'post']
            );
      }, 'class' => 'myclass']);
```